# Can't get access to any account in Liferay after migration to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, liferay, account

I created empty DB in PostgreSQL, started my lifery and when it loaded It shows me that window [image]

I entered my data but I didn't entered passsword field! And now I can't to login with administrative account! Also I changed password in DB but I had no luck! Help me pls!

Comment: Did u try 'test'?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal yes I tried! But it magicly solved. I don't know how! -_-

Comment: Hehehehe!May be I might have tweaked something remotely!! :)

Comment: that's the default password in Liferay! It does change from the usual "admin" or "password"

Answer (score 0):

In case where the default password doesn't work (The default password being "test").

The way to reset the admin password is to go into the database and update the user in the _user table. You have to change the password field with a clear text password and set to false the passwordEncrypted field.

You might have to restart liferay and then you should be able to login with that new password. Usually, after a successful login the password will be re encrypted in the database so it doesn't stay in clear text.